# If maskedTextBox after Read from Sql = null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I try to read date from Sql DB like this:

```
SqlCommand comm= new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce='" + tentoradek + "' AND rocnik='" + rocnik + "'", spojeni);
spojeni.Open();
SqlDataReader read= comm.ExecuteReader();

if (read.Read())
{
    object nulldate = (maskedTextBox2.Text = read.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString());
    if (nulldate == null)
    {
        maskedTextBox2.Text = "__.__.____";
    }

}
```

But the problém is when the value is null I need to have the maskedTextBox empty. I always get this exception: “This method or property cannot be called on Null values"

How can I avoid it with having the maskedTextBox empty when the value for particular column was read as NULL?

The mask on maskedTextBox is 00/00/0000

Thank you so much for answering my low-quality question.

Comment: you're very open to SQL attacks

Comment: Change your `If read.Read()` to `While(read.Read()){}` also change that dynamic sql from potentially sql injected code to implement Parameterized Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 object nulldate = (maskedTextBox2.Text = read.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString());
```

with

```
 object nulldate = (maskedTextBox2.Text = read.IsDBNull(24) ? string.Empty : read.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString());
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Something like this should do the trick</strike>

```
maskedTextBox2.Text = read.GetDateTime(24) != null 
    ? precti.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString()
    : "__.__.____";
```

**EDIT**

Above code is incorrect as `GetDateTime` doesn't work if data is `DbNull`. You have 2 options

1) Use field name instead of position

```
maskedTextBox2.Text = read["FieldName"] != null 
    ? ((DateTime)read.GetDateTime(24)).ToShortDateString()
    : "__.__.____";
```

2) Ask for DBNull before assigning

```
maskedTextBox2.Text = !reader.IsDBNull(24)
    ? reader.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString()
    : "__.__.____";
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answer, I tried that but still receiving the same Exception.

Comment: Are you sure @Claudio's answer is whats throwing that exception I would set some break points and verify.  My guess is that its this line object nulldate = (maskedTextBox2.Text = read.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString()); thats throwing the exception if you are implementing Claudio's answer along with this line I would suggest just removing the above line and only using Claudio's code.

Comment: I would recommend the `OP` also use a string.Format or maskedTextBox2.Text.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") something like that to format the date or use a `Parse` or `TryParse` function to make sure the date is valid

Comment: Only other option would be instead of null to check for a DbNUll.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what precti is, but I think this should be the SqlDataReader right?

However. Your reader has a method called `IsDbNull(INDEX)` where you can check if the specific column is DbNull or not.

Just for information:
You shouldn't build your SQL-Query like this:

```
SqlCommand comm= new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce='" + tentoradek + "' AND rocnik='" + rocnik + "'", spojeni);
```

Instead try the following code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce=@akce and rocnik=@rocnik", spojeni);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@akce", tentoradek);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rocnik", rocnik);
```